# MongoDB how to remove an element in an array of array?

Tags: c#, mongodb

The document is like this:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   results: [
      { item: "A", score: 5, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 4 }, { q: 2, a: 6 } ] },
      { item: "B", score: 8, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 8 }, { q: 2, a: 9 } ] }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 2,
   results: [
      { item: "C", score: 8, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 8 }, { q: 2, a: 7 } ] },
      { item: "B", score: 4, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 0 }, { q: 2, a: 8 } ] }
   ]
}
```

How could I remove the element of "answers" Not of "results"? 
Please help me!

---

I've tried many times but it just can remove element of "results".

```
db.collections.update(
  { "item":"C" },
  {$pull:{"results" :{ "answers": {   $elemMatch: { "q": 1 } }} }}
)
```

---

I can not get the index of element in sub-array. In fact there is a object stored in the sub-array, I want to remove the object by it's id.

---

I use **C#** Driver
This is my first question, the description may not be very clear, please forgive me

Comment: What is your research on this? please mention which language are you using..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what are your inputs to query & what is your desired o/p ?

Comment: You can use any of these [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) depending upon your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `$pull`:

```
db.your_collection.update(
   { _id : 2 },
   { $pull : { "results.0.answers" : { "q": 1 } } }
);
```

What this basically does is, searches for a document with `_id: 2`, and then removes (`pulls`) out the document in `results.X.answers` array where X is the `index` of the results array where the condition `{ "q" : 1 }` is true.

Comment: I think I can not get the index of what I want to remove. In my project, an object is stored in the sub-array, it has an id, I want to delete the object stored in the sub-array according to the id

Comment: I've tried your method, but I found that even the index is not match ( I used 0 as the index ) it really removed the element that matched the condition .It does work.

Comment: I finally understood this method, the index is not the index of the element that I want to remove. So before your method, I need to query the index by aggregate(). Fortunately ，it's easy, thank you so much!